# Waterline + Sails 0.10rc8/0.10rc9: beforeCreate not executing in sequence

Tags: sails.js, waterline

My models are based on waterline:

```
var Waterline = require('waterline');
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({..});
```

Here is my User.js

```
/**
 * User.js
 *
 * @description :: User Model
 * @docs    :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
 */
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var Waterline = require('waterline');
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

    connection: 'mongodb',

    attributes: {

        firstName: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        lastName: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        email: {
            type: 'email',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        username: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        slug: {
            type: 'string',
            unique: true
        },
        picUrl: {
            type: 'string',
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        activated: {
            type: 'boolean',
            defaultsTo: false
        },
        activationToken: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        // Add a reference to Questions/Stars
        starredQuestions: {
            collection: 'question',
            via: 'star',
            dominant: true
        },
        /**
         * Strips the password out of the json
         * object before its returned from waterline.
         * @return {object} the model results in object form
         */
        toJSON: function () {
            // this gives you an object with the current values
            var obj = this.toObject();
            delete obj.password;
            delete obj.email;
            delete obj.activationToken;
            delete obj.activated;
            // return the new object without password
            return obj;
        },
        /**
         * Adds a method called fullName to the response object
         * @return {string} firstName and LastName concat'd
         */
        fullName: function () {
            return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
        }
    },

    /**
     * Hash the users password with bcrypt
     * @param  {object}   user            the object of the submitted user data
     * @param  {Function} cb[err, user]   the callback to be used when bcrypts done
     */
    beforeCreate: function (user, cb) {
        console.log('inside before create');
        // create SLUG for better URLs.
        if (!user.username) {
            return cb({err: ["Must have a username!"]});
        }
        user.slug = user.username.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
        user.username = user.username.toLowerCase();
        user.stars = 0;
        user.likes = 0;
        // Create password + salt
        crypto.generate({saltComplexity: 10}, user.password, function (err, hash) {

            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            } else {
                user.password = hash;
                user.activated = false; //make sure nobody is creating a user with activate set to true, this is probably just for paranoia sake
                user.activationToken = crypto.token(new Date().getTime() + user.email);
                return cb(null, user);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the code which calls the Create() method:

```
create: function (req, res) {
    var params = req.params.all();
    User.findOne({'username' : params.username}, function (err, user) {
        User.create(params).exec(function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, err);
            } else {
                if (sails.config.user.requireUserActivation) {
                    var emailTemplate = res.render('email/email.ejs', {user: user}, function (err, list) {

                        nodemailer.send({
                            name: user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName,
                            from: sails.config.nodemailer.from,
                            to: user.email,
                            subject: 'New Account Acivation Required',
                            messageHtml: list
                        }, function (err, response) {
                            sails.log.debug('nodemailer sent', err, response);
                        });

                        // seed some questions here.

                        /*Question.create(params, function (err, question) {
                         if (err) {
                         res.send(500, err);
                         } else {
                         }
                         });*/

                        res.redirect('/success');

                    });
                } else {
                    res.redirect('/success');
                }
            }
        });
    });

},
```

I faced this on rc8 and then upgraded to rc9 and still facing the same issue.
What can be wrong?

Update: I added full code as requested by @particlebanana

Comment: We need more information to go off. Can you post your entire model?

Comment: Thank you @particlebanana - I just added the requested code above.

Comment: Waterline is built into Sails.  When using models in Sails, it's not necessary (or recommended) to require Waterline separately and extend the `Collection` class.  Simply set `module.exports` to your model class definition (the object containing `connection`, `attributes`, `beforeCreate`, etc.)